# Move periods inside quotes in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, punctuation, csquotes

I'm writing an article in Norwegian, and the guidelines specify that articles should be quoted in the bibliography as follows:

> John Doe. 2005. "My article." *A Cool Journal* 16.

My impression is that this is the default style in Norway. Abstracting away from other issues (which I can fix) I'm not able to replicate the quote style with `csquotes`. Using `style = norwegian` will use bottom quotes and put the period after the quotes. Using `style = american` gets me somewhat closer, but the period is still after the quotes. There's something in the `biblatex` manual under §3.10.1 about moving the periods inside the quotes, but I don't understand the documentation on this point.

With `style = norwegian`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[nynorsk]{babel}
\usepackage[style = norwegian, norwegian = quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp, language = nynorsk]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{myarticle,
    AUTHOR = "John Doe",
    TITLE = "My article",
    JOURNALTITLE = "A Cool Journal",
    VOLUME = "16",
    YEAR = "2005"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{myarticle}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `style = american`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[nynorsk]{babel}
\usepackage[style = american, norwegian = quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp, language = nynorsk]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{myarticle,
    AUTHOR = "John Doe",
    TITLE = "My article",
    JOURNALTITLE = "A Cool Journal",
    VOLUME = "16",
    YEAR = "2005"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{myarticle}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As a last resort, you can add a period at the end of the title in the .bib file. This will suppress the period after the quotes.

Comment: @Bernard I don't think it's a good idea to change the ``.bib`` file depending on the style sheet in question.

Comment: 'twas only a suggestion _as a last resort_.

Comment: I added a solution using `xpatch`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You simply have to tell `biblatex` to use the "American punctuation" for the `nynorsk` language, that is add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{nynorsk}{%
  \uspunctuation%
}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[nynorsk]{babel}
\usepackage[style = american, norwegian = quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp, language = nynorsk]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{myarticle,
    AUTHOR = "John Doe",
    TITLE = "My article",
    JOURNALTITLE = "A Cool Journal",
    VOLUME = "16",
    YEAR = "2005"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{nynorsk}{%
  \uspunctuation%
}

\begin{document}
\nocite{myarticle}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think you might be able to do this using `biblatex`'s `\uspunctuation` command (see sec. 4.7.5 p. 194 of the manual). This adds just one line to your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[nynorsk]{babel}
\usepackage[style = american, norwegian = quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp, language = nynorsk, backend = biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{myarticle,
    AUTHOR = "John Doe",
    TITLE = "My article",
    JOURNALTITLE = "A Cool Journal",
    VOLUME = "16",
    YEAR = "2005"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{myarticle}
\uspunctuation
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Obviously, move this earlier in the document if necessary. It does seem to need to follow `\begin{document}`, however. (I'd almost given up on getting something to work when I decided to try this command in the body of the document.) I assume something is getting run at `\begin{document}` which overrides settings configured in the preamble. (I guess to do with the document's primary language.)

[image: Norwegian (I assume) with US punctuation - Don't try this at home!]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, patching the `title` bibmacro – but it should be thoroughly tested for side effects, as there is after the modified fragment a \printfield{titleaddon}, for which I do not know whether this patch would be problematic. Also the title bibmacro is used for other types of entry, and in other bibmacros, so I included a test to see if we are in an article entry, but if it's OK for all types of entry that use "title", this test can be deleted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[nynorsk]{babel}
\usepackage[style = american, norwegian = quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp, language = nynorsk]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{title}{\printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
   {\printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}\ifentrytype{article}{\addperiod}{}}%
   {}{}%

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{myarticle,
AUTHOR = "John Doe",
TITLE = "My article",
JOURNALTITLE = "A Cool Journal",
VOLUME = "16",
YEAR = "2005"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{myarticle}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]