# period should come after double quote symbol for "title" field using biblatex.sty

Tags: biblatex

My codes are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}%
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,natbib=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\bibliography{test.bib}

\begin{document}

Test \citep{balafoutas2014direct}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

%%content of test.bib%%

```
@article{balafoutas2014direct,
  title={Book Title Field},
  author={XXX, YYY and ZZZ, AAA and BBB, CCC},
  journal={Proceedings of the XXX Academy of School},
  volume={0},
  number={1},
  pages={10-12},
  year={1978},
  publisher={Own Institution}
}
```

Required Output

[image]

I need to get the punctuation (period) after double closing quote symbol, refer the image, actually I've tried [Punctuation Outside of Quotes for Biblatex + SBL + Polyglossia](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370313/punctuation-outside-of-quotes-for-biblatex-sbl-polyglossia) but it didn't help with my requirement, please suggest...

Note that I'm using `MikTeX V2.9` on `Windows10` system

Comment: Can you show an image of the output from the MWE, please? I probably misunderstand what is going on, but I already get the period after the quotation marks in your example.

Comment: Period is coming for me too, but i need to print as period following by a closing double quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MWE produces

[image: YYY XXX, AAA ZZZ, and CCC BBB. “Book Title Field”. In: Proceedings of the XXX Academy of School 0.1 (1978), pp. 10–12.]

with the period after the closing quotation marks, i.e. *outside* the quotation marks, as in the image for me.

I'm assuming you want the period *inside* the quotation marks. This would be "US punctuation" in `biblatex` speak and can be obtained either by

1. Using `american` instead of the generic `english` as document language.
2. Setting `\uspunctuation` also for `english`.

MWE for the second option

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}%
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,natbib=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \uspunctuation
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{balafoutas2014direct,
  title={Book Title Field},
  author={XXX, YYY and ZZZ, AAA and BBB, CCC},
  journal={Proceedings of the XXX Academy of School},
  volume={0},
  number={1},
  pages={10-12},
  year={1978},
  publisher={Own Institution},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Test \citep{balafoutas2014direct}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: YYY XXX, AAA ZZZ, and CCC BBB. “Book Title Field.” In: Proceedings of the XXX Academy of School 0.1 (1978), pp. 10–12.]

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/194557/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/157385/35864

Comment: Yes, your guess is exactly correct, I need the `US punctuation` style and both your suggestion works like a champ... Thanks a lot...